# How to warp an image to 3D plane in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am sorry that people had asked this, but the solution does not work. 
Here's [the problem link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/366084-3d-reconstruction-from-a-2d-image). I am using matlab to project the 2d image of one camera onto the 3d plane through intrinsic and extrinsic parameters, and then re-project it to another camera.How to bring up color information into reprojected points?

Assume a pixel in image1 is [u1,v1], it corresponds to the point[X,Y] in the world.P1 and P2 are respectively projection matrixes of two cameras.

```
[u1,v1] = [X,Y,1]*[R1;t1]*K1 = [X,Y,1]*P1
[u2,v2] = [X,Y,1]*[R2;t2]*K2 = [X,Y,1]*P2
[u2,v2] = [u1,v1]*inv(P1)*P2
```

so the tform should be inv(P1)*P2

According to the solution of the link,I use function"imwarp" in matlab.

```
imwarp(img, perspecticv2d( P1\P2 ));
```

it's good that it has color information. However, image position is not right.Did I use it  wrong ?

And I tried another solution.

```
[m,n,c]= size(I);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:m, 1:n);
imagePoints = [X(:) Y(:) ones(m*n,1)];
```

I project image-points to world and the re-project them to camera.It works well in position,but How can I bring up color information into the projected image?

I expect the output image with color and good position
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your second code works, what is the problem with the color? If you have the transformation of the coordinates, then you know where to sample the original image to obtain the colors right? A color image is just 3 gray images, so treat it like that

Comment: I really appreciate your patience in answering my questions. I've tried to add color information in red:
`color = img1(:,:,1);`
`color = reshape(color,m*n,1);`
`pixelwithcolor = [nonint_pixel_2d color];`
pixelwithcolor = reshape(pixelwithcolor,m,n,3);
`
It seems the position values mix with color information?

Comment: I have no idea what that code is supposed to do, you are only reshaping stuff, there is no math applied.  Read what a [mcve] is and why you are required to add one to ask in SO.